# Java Client Consuming .NET WCF over SSL (WS-Policy not supported)

Tags: java, c#, wcf, ssl, appian

I have a .NET 4.0 WCF service hosted in IIS on Windows Server 2008 which is running just fine over HTTP. The WCF service is being consumed by a third party, who is using Appian Process Modeler to configure the WCF client (not that it's relevant, but I thought I'd mention it).

**EDIT: So the fact they're using Appian Process Modeler may actually be relevant. It's a Java-based client, so that means we're trying to get a Java client to consume a .NET WCF service using WS-Policy over SSL.**

**EDIT #2: Since I now know that Java is consuming a .NET service, is this a fix I can do on my end to allow Java to consume my service over SSL, or is there a fix my client can put in place to allow their Java code to consume a .NET service using WS-Policy?**

After moving from test, to our production environment, when our client updates their service reference to point to the new production URL, they get the following error:

**The endpoint BasicHttpBinding_IInterface contains references to a WS-Policy subject, which is not yet supported. That endpoint is not available for selection. (APNX-2-4041-003)**

In comparing the two WSDL documents (non-SSL/test, SSL/production) I found the following  two differences, both related to WS-Policy (these are the ONLY two differences, except for URLs, in the WSDL document):

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_IInterface_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:TransportToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportToken>
            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Basic256/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <sp:Layout>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Strict/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Layout>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:TransportBinding>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
```

And

```
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BasicHttpBinding_IInterface_policy"/>
```

I attempted to create a static WSDL document in production with those two sections removed, but I can't generate a secure connection to the WCF service if I do that.

**So my question is, how do I configure WCF to respond over SSL without the WS-Policy requirements?**

Here is the configuration we're using on the server:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="basicHttps">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    <message />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client />
    <services>
      <service name="Namespace.API.IInterface_Implementation">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="basicHttps"
                  contract="Namespace.API.Interfaces.IInterface"/>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, this does not appear to be possible.

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/89dcf73c-ff5c-4f7d-b373-bba0f5f6eadb/) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/2920ccd6-9b95-4285-908f-283057aab2b6).

The authentication modes and corresponding prefixes and namespaces are discussed in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738565.aspx). This may give you some additional ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the links. I think my question has become more of a "how do I get a Java client to consume my .NET WCF service over SSL", rather than "how can I turn off WS-Policy". I upvoted your answer though for the links which did provide some insight into my original question.

Comment: @Scott: Here is a really good article on that very subject: http://honga.super6.cz/2011/07/aspnet-forms-authentication-and-java.html

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I think this is something that needs to happen on the Java side to get it to work. This article does help though. I'm going to leave the question open for a bit though to see if anyone else has specific suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: The URL above is not working any more. It has been moved to: hoonzis.blogspot.com/2011/07/aspnet-forms-authentication-and-java.html
On the other hand - I have to say, that your issue seems to particular and you won't be able to find the solution there.

Comment: you can implement this.. is not that hard.. you just have to know what you have to send :)